# blazor components approach performance

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Recently working around to create blazor component, I have stuck with certain questions.

1. What is the best approach to creating components( Native & Or Using Existing JavaScript UI)
2. Is there any performance or memory leaks in choosing Existing JavaScript.
3. Any impacts in Serve Side blazor While Using JavaScript Lib components.
4. What are the pros and cons between both approaches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. There is only a single approach in Blazor - creating Blazor UI components. Both Angular and Blazor are UI Component frameworks. The first employs JavaScript, the later employs C#, though you may use JSInterop when you can't otherwise.
2. There might be some memory leaks when C# code is waiting for JavaScript response while JavaScript code "is not sure what to do". In that case, and as far as I remember, the Blazor framework is going to stop this nonsense after a certain time.
3. The objective of Blazor is to use JavaScript, as little as possible. Blazor is not a JavaScript framework. And it employs JavaScript in order to communicate with the DOM, at least until Web Assembly is mature enough to enable direct communication with the DOM, without the mediation of JavaScript .

Start learning Blazor... Blazor is awesome...
Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, @issac. In Blazor faq page, They have answered we can use existing javascript. I hope they maybe have the way to achieve and fix leaks(https://blazor.net/docs/introduction/faq.html).